# Permission in AzureAD for scaling up and down with REST API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I have registered an application in AzureAD: `AnalysisService` 
It has the following IDs:

```
Application (client) ID: ID1
Directory (tenant) ID: ID2
```

and I have defined the following permission it:
[image]

My aim is scaling up and down my `Azure Analysis Service` in logic app with the following ID

```
Subscription ID: ID3
```

In logic app I have the following request:

```
{
    "uri": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**ID3**/resourceGroups/ServerName/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/Model?api-version=2017-08-01",
    "method": "PATCH",
    "authentication": {
        "tenant": "ID2",
        "audience": "https://management.core.windows.net",
        "clientId": "ID1",
        "secret": "*sanitized*",
        "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
    },
    "body": {
        "sku": {
            "capacity": 1,
            "name": "S4",
            "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "tags": {
            "testKey": "testValue"
        }
    }
}
```

After sending this request I get the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "x-ms-failure-cause": "gateway",
        "x-ms-request-id": "xxxxxx-4dea-xxx-xxxx-xxx",
        "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-4dea-xxxx-xxxx-5dea12ba0cca",
        "x-ms-routing-request-id": "WESTEUROPE:20190211T181536Z:xxxxxx-4dea-4fa8-bccd-xxxxxx",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Mon, 11 Feb 2019 18:15:35 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "413",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "-1"
    },
    "body": {
        "error": {
            "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
            "message": "Client \"ID4\" with the object ID \"ID4\" has no permission to run the action \"Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/write\" over \"/subscriptions/ID3/resourceGroups/ServerName/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/ModelName\"."
        }
    }
}
```

what should I do more to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
I have granted my service principal (which represents Azure AD application) the following specific permissions over my Analysis Services instance:

[image]

I have also control it in management studio as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-addservprinc-admins) and I can see the serviceprincipal also there:
[image]

But I get still the same error message

Is the `ID4`, the object ID of my logic app? should I add my logic app also in IAM of my Analysis Service?

Comment: you sure your logic app acts on behalf of your service principal?

Comment: No, I am not sure. Where Can I find the Object ID of my logic app? nowhere I found it. If you need more information. I can provide you ^^

Comment: ok, wait, I'm tripping. you sure you granted ID4 permissions to do that operation? just grant that account contributor on subscription level for now

Comment: well to be ohnes I dont know exactly where the `ID4` come from. My service Proncipal, which I defined in AzureAD (first Figure) has also another ID. I should ask  our admin to do that. :/  Tomorrow I will tell you the result

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to grant id4 those permissions, since your logic app appears to be uing that

Comment: Is it possible to see which Object ID does my Logic App have? I would like to be sure, that ÌD4`belongs really to logic app

Comment: logic app doesnt really have an object id, it has resource id, but its using some application behind the scenes

Answer (score 2):

You should grant your service principal (which represents Azure AD application) those specific permissions: `Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/write` over your Analysis Services instance: `/subscriptions/ID3/resourceGroups/ServerName/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/ModelName`. Alternatively, you can grant those permissions on the resource group level, or subscription level.

Here's how you do it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal.

In short: go to the resource, click IAM on the left, click `+ Add Role Assignment` on the top of the blade and pick your role\identity. This particular permissions falls under something like Analysis Services contributor.

ps. you can always create a custom role to follow least privilege principle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles

Comment: Thank you so much, can you explain to me something? As I understood my Identity has not enough permission to scale up and down the AzureAS. Correct? I have controlled my Access in IAM on the AS.  `contributor` --> "manage everything except access to resources" is assigned to me.  But I can scale up and down  this AzureAS in Azure Portal. Why can I do that in Azure Portal but not with REST API?

Comment: because on the portal you act as a User (you cant login to the portal with you Azure AD application) and when you talk to the API from your application you act on behalf of the application, so its 2 different entities, with different permissions

Comment: You mean that I should Add the App, which I defined in AzureAD, into the IAM in AzureAS with contributor role.Then the APP can behave like my Identity and able to scale up and down the AS. Correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct. grant your application service principal permissions and you are good (application cant have permissions, you have to create a service principal if its not there and grant it permissions)